# Same table with different name Mapping NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have multiple table in database with exactly same schema but different table name.

table_1
{
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
}
.
.
table_2
{
   col1,
   col2,
   col3,
}

I wanted to keep single mapping HBM file and model class. I tried creating different Naming strategy but the problem is to pass table name from Repository class and perform DB actions. Solution of this problem is much appreciated since I am new to NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to map these tables to the same object or different objects? 
Honestly, I do not think you can do it, HBM files are stored as resources in the DLL and can not be edited dynamically.